# Determining $x_2$ in the solution of the system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

**Task:**
Determine $x_2$ in the solution of the system$$
\begin{bmatrix}4&a&0\\6&b&2\\9&c&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}$$when$$
\left|\begin{matrix}4&a&0\\6&b&2\\9&c&3\end{matrix}\right|=4$$
using Cramer's rule.

**Options to choose from:**

1. $-4$
2. $4$
3. $6$
4. $-2$

**My answer:**
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}×4=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

I got $x_2=\dfrac24$ which is not an option to choose. How do I do?

Comment: Do you mean determinant of matrix is $4$?

Comment: The information that I get from the task is that the 3x3 matrix is equal to 4

Comment: The vertical lines are just another notion for the determinant of a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

$\underline{\text{Cramer's rule:}}$ $x_i=\dfrac{\Delta_i}{\Delta }$ where $\Delta_i$ is the determinant of matrix $A$ with its $i^{th}$ column replaced by vector $b$ and $\Delta$ is the determinant of the matrix $A$.

> $$x_2=\dfrac{\left|\begin{matrix}4 &1 &0\\6 &2 &2\\9 &0 &3\end{matrix}\right|}{4}=\dfrac{24}{4}=6$$

Comment: what is the second column in A?

Comment: Its $(a\: b\: c)^T$

Comment: what does the delta mean?

Comment: Delta means determinant of matrix concerned.

Comment: sorry for being stupid but I don't understand how I should do

Comment: For $x_2$, first replace the vector $b=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}$ with the $2^{nd}$ column of $A$, and then calculate the determinant using [Laplace expansion for determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion). Then $x_2$=ratio the determinant of the new(altered) matrix with the original  determinant of the matrix $A$

Comment: thanks for your help. I got it to 6